# Python iterate through object to create tables with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, class, flask-sqlalchemy

EDITED
I've been trying to create an class that will allow me to iterate through a list, or dictionary, and generate tables and rows.
The code starts as follows:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as sa
from flask import Flask as fl
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = fl(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:the_other_stuff'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] =False
DEBUG =True
db = sa(app)

a=['some_stuff','gaaahhhh','lalala','rawr','pizza']

class test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stuff'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.Unicode(50))

    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data

def stuff():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        data= a[i]
        i = i + 1
        id = i
        db.session.add(test(id,data))
    db.create_all()
    return db.session.commit()
stuff()
```

I'm still going to try and structure it so that it can take a dictionary, or list, and then add the key as the table name if it is a dict. If someone has that code, I won't argue with you sharing, but if not I'll post when that is done.

Comment: Please refrain from completely rewriting questions in to new questions, because it undermines the existing answers. If you have a new question, ask it as such.

Comment: The answer was so simple, I decided to post the immediate fix, and then upload the full code snippet after it was finished so that the code could match the header. I just finished it tonight, and thank you for the help on that btw. I sent it to a friend to double check it was good, and I'll put it up when I hear back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `db.session.add` / `db.session.commit`. `db` object is initialized from `flask_sqlalchemy`. It is not **db.Session**.

Comment: well... yeah that totally fixed that error. It brings up an index error now, but I'll post a solution to that on here in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

The below code auto inserts data into a one-to-many relationship table set. The recursive function acts like a while loop (%timeit showed the same results for both) I just like the way it looks over a while loop. *The function will index to a list in a list, I was going 3 deep but modified the loops to simply.* **This was originally designed to push a list like so:** `list[a][i][0]` each zero value inside every `[i]` was the same value type, I set it to only do `[a][i]` to keep it a little more simple, and so it could be used as as base if someone liked it. `[a][i][0]` was very fast, but `[a][i]` might be better off as a list of `pd.DataFrame`, instead of as `np.array`. If `[i]` is not going to the same `db.Column()` you'll have to declare one for each set of `[i]` and figure out a way of indexing through it.
A table generator involves a class generator with a base class. I don't have a working example, but can upload when I do

```
import numpy as np
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as sa
from flask import Flask as fl
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = fl(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:the_other_stuff'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] =False
DEBUG =True
db = sa(app)

list=[np.array(np.ones(100)),np.array(np.ones(100)),np.array(np.ones(100)),
      np.array(np.ones(100)),np.array(np.ones(100))]

class Parent(db.Model):

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data= db.Column('data', db.VARCHAR(45))

    _child = db.relationship('child', backref='parent', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Parent %r>' % self.id

class Child(db.Model):

    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.VARCHAR(45))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Parent.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Parent')

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Child %r>' % self.id


def child_loop(i = 0):
    for a in range(len(list)):
        with db.session.no_autoflush:
            try:
                p = Parent(symbol_col=data[a])
                c = child(data = list[a][i])
                s.c.append(child)
                db.session.add(p)
                db.session.add(c)

            except exc.IntegrityError as e:
                db.session.rollback()

    i = i + 1
    if a < len(list[0]):
        child_loop(i = i)
    return print('inserted open_close')
child_loop(i=0)
```